# Specify a default solution when debugging with the experimental instance

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

When working with Visual Studio Extensions and debugging using the experimental instance, is it possible to have the experimental instance automatically load a solution?

I did not see options, but may have been looking in the wrong place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just right click on your project in Solution Explorer and hit properties. Debug tab. You'll see "command line arguments" as a box, which should contain "/rootsuffix Exp". These arguments are what are used to launch devenv.exe (the Visual Studio process). If you just add the full path to your solution after what is already there (quote if necessary), that should work just fine. It's really no different than doing devenv.exe  from the command line.

Comment: And as an aside...I'm going to do that with all of my stuff now, I think. :-)